# SQLite no such table error when table exists in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

This is How I define my table as what this link: [SQLite no such table error when table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440904/sqlite-no-such-table-error-when-table-exists) said

```cs
[Table("RegUserTable")]
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class RegUserTable
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Login code:

```cs
public void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)//LOGIN!
{
    var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Userdatabase.db");
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
    var loginquery = db.Table<RegUserTable>().Where(u => u.Username.Equals(EntryLoginUsername.Text) && u.Password.Equals(EntryLoginPassword.Text)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EntryLoginUsername.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EntryLoginPassword.Text))
    {
        DisplayAlert("Blank Fields", "Please Input Your Username and Password!", "OK");
    }
    else if (loginquery != null)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(EntryLoginUsername.Text, GenderIdentifier.Text));
    }
}
```

If I run this in my emulator it works 100%, but when I run it on my device it throws this error: 
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For starters remove DataMember and Contract, it's not needed, secondly, make sure you are connecting to the correct database in case if you have multiple. Third show us the code where you are adding this table to you db!

Comment: Thank you for saying the "Third"

I just Added This

var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);
            {
                connection.CreateTableAsync<RegUserTable>();
            }   

now it works :D 

I did not add that at the beginning because my code (above) is just working fine in the emulator.

Comment: Added an answer kindly mark it for others who are looking for the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the table something like below solves the issue

```cs
public async void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)//LOGIN!
{
    var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Userdatabase.db");
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);

    var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath); 
    await connection.CreateTableAsync<RegUserTable>();

    var loginquery = db.Table<RegUserTable>().Where(u => u.Username.Equals(EntryLoginUsername.Text) && u.Password.Equals(EntryLoginPassword.Text)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EntryLoginUsername.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EntryLoginPassword.Text))
    {
        DisplayAlert("Blank Fields", "Please Input Your Username and Password!", "OK");
    }
    else if (loginquery != null)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(EntryLoginUsername.Text, GenderIdentifier.Text));
    }
}
```